# Classifying Duplicates in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very large excel file(150,000+ accounts) with duplicate account names. I want to group the duplicate accounts below and classify them in the sixth column based on criteria.

```
  Account Name   Account ZIP   Account ID   Account Owner   Owner Role   Class  
 -------------- ------------- ------------ --------------- ------------ ------
  ZZZ Inc              12345        99877   Lanky Larry     AM                  
  ZZZ                  12345                No Owner        OTHER               

  ABC Corp             00512                Scuba Steve     SAM                 
  ABC Corp             00512                Scuba Steve     SAM                 
  ABC Corp             00512         8564   Scuba Steve     SAM
```

For ZZZ Inc and ZZZ the classification should be "green" because there is only one account ID for ZZZ inc, that cell for count ZZZ is empty.

For the three ABC Corp accounts there is only one account ID, BUT Scuba Steve's role is SAM, which trumps all else, in this case the classification should be "y".

I wrote some code in an attempt to group the accounts and then compare them, but I am hitting a dead end. A runtime error is returned when I run the code as "Overflow", any advice or suggestions would be much appreciated.

The reason I am searching for blank rows is because that is what separates each duplicate grouping like in the table above.

```
Sub Classification()
   Dim myRange As Range
    Dim rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim firstBlankRow As Integer, lastBlankRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String
    Dim nextRowValue As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Stop screen updating while grouping

'select range based on given named range
    Set myRange = Range("A1:A190000")
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, myRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    firstBlankRow = 0
    lastBlankRow = 0

'for every row in the range
    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, myRange.Column).Value
    nextRowValue = Cells(currentRow + 1, myRange.Column).Value

'Assign firstBlankRow & lastBlankRow
    'if currentRowValue = NotBlank(Job#) And nextRowValue = NotBlank(Job#) Then Skip
    'if currentRowValue = Blank          And nextRowValue = Blank          Then Skip
    'if currentRowValue = NotBlank(Job#) And nextRowValue = Blank          Then is firstBlankRow
    'if currentRowValue = Blank          And nextRowValue = NotBlank(Job#) Then is lastBlankRow
    If Not (currentRowValue = "" Or currentRowValue = "") Then
        If (IsEmpty(nextRowValue) Or nextRowValue = "") Then
            firstBlankRow = currentRow + 1
        End If
    ElseIf (IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "") Then
        If Not (IsEmpty(nextRowValue) Or nextRowValue = "") Then
            If firstBlankRow <> 0 Then
                lastBlankRow = currentRow
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Debug.Print "Row " & currentRow; ": firstBlankRow: " & firstBlankRow; ", lastBlankRow: " & lastBlankRow

'Group firstBlankRow & lastBlankRow
    'if first & last blank rows have been assigned, create a group
    If firstBlankRow <> 0 And lastBlankRow <> 0 Then
        'Debug.Print "Row: " & currentRow; ", Outline Level: " & ActiveSheet.Rows(currentRow).OutlineLevel
        If Not ActiveSheet.Rows(currentRow).OutlineLevel > 1 Then 'Ignore if last row is already grouped
            Range(Cells(firstBlankRow, myRange.Column), Cells(lastBlankRow, myRange.Column)).EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Group
        End If
        firstBlankRow = 0: lastBlankRow = 0 'reset the first/lastBlankRow values to 0
    End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use the power of Excel to achieve your outcome? One way is to use a pivot table and display the count of each account. Additionally, you could use a INDEX|MATCH or a LOOKUP top populate the column. The first allows for a sorted result easily, the second probably requires a sort of the data periodically as new information is provided. If this is the data, then a manual sort may suffice for the effort involved.

Comment: … or you could do a "COUNTIF"! The principle here is to "keep it simple" and only use VBA for those issues that really need it.

Comment: `Integer` limit is about 32,000 - you should use `Long`

Comment: `Integer` Used to hold any whole number between -32,768 and 32,767. `Long` Used to hold any whole number between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,486,647